# Adding time on recent orders for woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I need to add the time on the account page for when a customer has placed an order through woocommerce.

I just need to display the time right next to the date of the account page on 'recent orders'.

Like so:

[image: display example]

I know one can edit the my-orders.php but I am not sure of how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this, with playing and breaking the site, in view-order.php woocommerce has a 'display time' 'if' statement with a time signature on there. So in the my-orders.php around line 53, in the  tag replace this:

```
<?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php echo date_i18n( __( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>
```

This will ensure, as stated here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp, you include the Day - 'l', in words of 'F Y' the current year the time 'h:ia' with an am or pm.

Obvioulsly this feature is really specific but if your woocommerce business relies on exactitudes, then this can be really handy for your customers and backend.